# Плагин вместо русских букв пишет иероглифами

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

Я делаю плагин на Minecraft 1.8, когда игрок заходит на сервер, в чат ему должно написаться приветствие, но вместо этого пишет это [image: скрин чата]. Как можно плагин заставить писать на русском? Код сообщения:

```
public void join(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    String s = plugin.getConfig().getString("messages.main.onjoin");
    s = s.replace("&", "\u00a7");
    p.sendMessage(s);
}
```

В конфиге messages.main.onjoin написан на русском.

Если код будет такой:

```
public void join(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    p.sendMessage("Привет");
}
```

То в чате будет написано на русском "Привет".

Comment: конфиг файл в какой кодировке сохранён?

Comment: UTF-8. Менял на UTF-8 с BOM, всё тоже самое

Comment: Причем, если я отправлю сообщение без string, тобишь p.sendMessage("Привет"), он напишет на русском.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте запустить это в самом начале кода

```
public static void setStandatCharSets(){
    
    try {
        System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
        Field charset = null;
        try {
            charset = Charset.class.getDeclaredField("defaultCharset");
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    charset.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            charset.set(null, null);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```